# How can i create my own block-list for Pi-Hole?

Tags: raspbian, pi-hole

I didn't select any host list at the installation, now how can i create my own block-list for Pi-Hole? 
 Do i need to create a *.sh* file or a *.txt*? 
*Obs: I am using Raspbian to run Pi-Hole.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the standard lists that can be set at install time you can set them active at x.x.x.x/admin/settings.php?tab=blocklists where x.x.x.x is the IP or name of the Pi running Pi-Hole.

This can also be reached by:

- Log into the admin console
- Select the *Settings* option from the left menu
- Select Blacklist from the top tabs
- Select the ones you want to use by ticking the 'Enabled' box for each list
- Select the Save and Update (not just the Save)

The other ways of importing block lists are:

- Log in to pi-hole via the admin screen
- Settings
- Blocklists
- Add any specific URLS of your own
- Select Save and repeat for any more of your own URLs
- Finally Save and update (not just save)

Blacklisted domains are stored in  /etc/pihole/blacklist.txt - DO NOT edit this directly!

You normally use the Pi-hole admin screen to do this.

- Log-in as normal
- Select Blacklist from the menu
- Enter the domains / regex pattern in

You can also add domains from the command line

```
pihole -b -f domain1 [domain2...]
```

use ‘-w’ for WHITELIST changes
The -f forces the reload of dnsmasq after the import so it’s up to date

Edit: The settings / teleporter function allows you to import any blacklist or regex file from a Mac (and I assume a PC) via two files.

- Normal blacklist entries should be in a linefeed terminated file - one domain to a line.
- RegEx entries should be in a linefeed terminated file - one pattern to a line.

File names **must be** *blacklist.txt* and *regex.list* respectively AND they must be wrapped up into a *.tar.gz* file. To import:

- Log in to the admin console
- Settings / Teleporter
- Select the file using the 'choose file' button
- Select blacklist and or regex from the left hand side
- Hit the import button

Comment: I guess the Pi Hole admin has changed, because there is no Blacklist-tab on the Settings page.